# adding php inside of mysql_query Warning

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

I'm extremly new to php and now i try to add this code: `<?php echo $user_info['username']; ?>`inside on line 5:

```
 <? // counter.php
if (!isset($_GET['show']) || $_COOKIE['cookietracker'] != 1) {
$conid = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Can't connect to database");
mysql_select_db("servers");
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET points=points+1 WHERE username='<?php echo $user_info['username']; ?>'");
mysql_close($conid); unset($query);
setcookie("countertracker",1,time()+7200);
} else {
$query=mysql_query("SELECT points FROM login");
$result = mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo $result['points'];
}
?>
```

But when i do that i get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\servers\user_profiles\profile.php on line 5`
i'we been searching alot!

Any suggestions?

Comment: may be a little more advanced, but take a loot at using PDO. You can prepare statements to deal with stuff like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET points=points+1 WHERE username='".$user_info['username']."'");
```

Comment: i'm geting: Notice: Undefined variable: user_info in servers\user_profiles\profile.php on line 5. That might be something else? but dont know how to fix i guess:S

Comment: Move the query that you're getting `$user_info` from above the query that we're helping you with.

Comment: when i moved it above it worked, thanks sean! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're already in the PHP syntax so you just need to concatenate the variable into the string. Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET points=points+1 WHERE username='" . $user_info['username'] . "'");
```

Comment: wierdly enought it i says: Notice: Undefined variable: user_info in servers\user_profiles\profile.php on line 5

Comment: That's a different error completely :) You just need to make sure that variable is defined before referencing it.

Comment: i use: <?php echo $user_info['username']; ?> longer down in the codes, and it works fine. maby something there? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$query = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET points=points+1 WHERE username='" . $user_info['username'] . "'");`

You are already in PHP, so you don't need to redeclare that you are in PHP. You are simply concatenating a string.

Comment: i'm geting: Notice: Undefined variable: user_info in servers\user_profiles\profile.php on line 5. That might be something else? but dont know how to fix i guess:S

Comment: That means your $user_info variable doesn't exist in that scope. From the code listed above, you haven't declared `$user_info` anywhere in the script. Where does it get it's data?